# Sending an email through a Boostrap Modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, email

Im working on my webpage and I would to send an email through a modal. Meaning the user click the email button. The #emailModal shows up with 3 input sections. Email, Subject, and Content. I would like it to send the email to the email address the user enters once the user clicks the send email button.

**My question is different** because I want to send an email to my clients, so click on a button I enter their email, the subject matter, and the content.

**Home.php**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="emailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="emailModalLabel">
                      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="emailModalLabel">Email</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <form class="form-horizontal method="post" role="form" action="send_email_form.php"">
                            <fieldset>

                            <!-- Form Name -->
                            <legend>Email</legend>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email:</label>  
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                              <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="placeholder@gmail.com" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="subject">Subject:</label>  
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                              <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">

                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Textarea -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="content">Content:</label>
                              <div class="col-md-4">                     
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content"></textarea>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            </fieldset>
                            </form>

                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send Email</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

**send_email_form.php**

```
 $to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['content'];

$headers = "From: info@demo.com".phpversion();

<?php 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

here is my php file, when i click the submit button nothing is appearing to happen. I know my php is basic, im just looking for something very simple and to the point.

Comment: why don't you simply give action method to form where you can write code to send email

Comment: 3 seconds on Google http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/working-bootstrap-contact-form/

Comment: @Arvaan i added method="post"

Comment: and where's the PHP that goes with this? and errors, if any?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am looking to SEND an email to my clients, Meaning I enter their email address, the subject matter, and the content. I am not trying to create a contact form for my page for people to email ME

Comment: @Fred-ii- ive added my .php

Comment: you most likely have a syntax error somewhere. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.  This is questionable `$headers = "From: info@demo.com".phpversion();` and am not sure if you do have your mail stuff inside PHP tags. Read the manual on mail also http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- nothing happens when i click the submit button. no errors or anyhting, it doesnt even change the page

Comment: plus, `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send Email</button>` is outside your form tags. probably why it's not sending. do that and try `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Email</button>` if it still doesn't work. It must be inside your form tags.

Comment: You're missing a quote in your form class attribute. Really basic error.